# Failure to identify and concatenate using a capture group identified with regex as reference

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, replace, regex-group

```py
import re

input_text = 'desde las 15:00 del 2002-11-01 hasta las 16 hs' #example
```

I have placed the pattern `(?:(?<=\s)|^)` in front so that it only detects if it is the beginning of the string or if there are one or more whitespaces in front. Then there are other matches that must be present. And finally there is the time which is missing the minutes, and the program must add `:00`

```py
input_text = re.sub(r'(?:(?<=\s)|^)(?:a[\s|]*las|a[\s|]*la|de[\s|]*las|de[\s|]*la)\s*(\d{1,2})[\s|]*(?::|)[\s|]*(?:h\. s\.|h s\.|h\. s|h s|h\.s\.|hs\.|h\.s|hs|horas|hora)', r'\1:00 hs', input_text)

print(repr(input_text)) # ---> output
```

I couldn't do a regular concatenation either because I don't know what could be next in the string.

I'm not really getting the proper replacement using this search regex pattern, and the correct output is this:

```
'desde las 15:00 del 2002-11-01 hasta las 16:00 hs'
```

I think that the `(\d{1,2})` capture group is failing and that is why it is not correctly replaced in the `\1`

Comment: Do not use `(?:(?<=\s)|^)`, there is a shorter and simpler identical pattern - `(?<!\S)`. Also, `(?::|)` = `:?`

Comment: So, in the first place, you should not have used `(?:(?<=\s)|^)` because it does not allow you to match `a`  in `hasta`.

Comment: You need to enumarate the prepositions, see `\b(?:de(?:sde)?|(?:hast)?a)\s*las?\s*(\d{1,2})\s*(?::\s*)?(?:h\.? ?s\.?|horas?)(?!\B\w)`. You might want to add more, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xsBsMS/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you very much, I was having that problem with the letter "a" of the word "hasta", since I ignored that restricting the "a" generated that "hasta" also remain as a restricted case, preventing it from being preceded by words that end with the letter "a"

Comment: So what are the pattern requirements? Do you have a specific list of words you need to support before the time string? Maybe you also want to support a specific hour format? Please add these requirements to the question so that this problem could be definitively solved, and you do not have to post more questions like this (you have already posted a lot).

Comment: In the end, just modify one detail leaving this regex and it works fine `input_text = re.sub(r'\b(?:de(?:sde)?|(?:hast)?a|)\s*las?\s*(\d{1,2})\s*(?::\s*)?(?:h\.? ?s\.?|horas?)(?!\B\w)', r'\1:00 hs', input_text)`. 
Regarding the questions on the subject, I know I've asked a lot but really establishing an information extraction control associated with time is an interesting question for me to practice regex at a more advance level, even so I thank you very much for the help, and despite the language differences, you have helped me a lot

Comment: So you want to make the preposition optional? In that case using a word boundary should be restricted to the optional group. It should be `\b((?:(?:de(?:sde)?|(?:hast)?a)\s*)?las?\s*\d{1,2})\s*(?::\s*)?(?:h\.? ?s\.?|horas?)(?!\B\w)`, see https://regex101.com/r/xsBsMS/2. However, it means you might as well use `\b(las?\s*\d{1,2})\s*(?::\s*)?(?:h\.? ?s\.?|horas?)(?!\B\w)`, see https://regex101.com/r/xsBsMS/3

Comment: I think the best restriction is that the letter `"a"` belonging to `"(?:hasta a las|hasta a la|hasta las|hasta la|a las|a la|a)"` is preceded by a whitespace or that it is the beginning of the string ( in case it is at the beginning of the string).

Comment: This last regex that you have passed me, I think, that is the most generical regex for this case `\b(las?\s*\d{1,2})\s*(?::\s*)?(?:h\.? ?s\.?|horas?)(?!\B\w)`, and which can be extended to similar cases directly like this  `'\b(las?\s*\d{1,2})\s*(?:a.m.|a.m|am.|am|p.m.|p.m|pm.|pm|)\s*(?::\s*)?(?:h\.? ?s\.?|horas?)(?!\B\w)'` or this `'\b(las?\s*\d{1,2})\s*(?:a\.?m\.?|p\.?m\.?|)\s*(?::\s*)?(?:h\.? ?s\.?|horas?)(?!\B\w)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may solve the current issue using

```py
re.sub(r'(?<!\S)((?:de(?:sde)?|(?:hast)?a)\s*las?\s*\d{1,2})\s*(?::\s*)?(?:h\.? ?s\.?|horas?)(?!\B\w)', r'\1:00 hs', input_text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xsBsMS/5). Please pay attention at the pattern description below:

- `(?<!\S)` - a left-hand whitespace boundary
- `((?:de(?:sde)?|(?:hast)?a)\s*las?\s*\d{1,2})` - Group 1 (`\1` refers to this value from the replacement pattern):

  - `(?:de(?:sde)?|(?:hast)?a)` - `de`, `desde`, `hasta`, `a`
  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `las?` - `la` or `las`
  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `\d{1,2}` - one or two digits (**note** you might want to use `(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])` to only match numbers from `0` to `23` to match 24h time format)
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(?::\s*)?` - an optional sequence of a colon and zero or more whitespaces
- `(?:h\.? ?s\.?|horas?)` - `h`, then an optional `.`, then an optional space, then an `s` and then an optional `.`, or `hora` or `horas`
- `(?!\B\w)` - adaptive dynamic word boundary, if there is a word char on the left, the word boundary is required.